# Group by month and name SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I need some help with SQL.

I have

- `Table1` with columns `Id`, `Date1` and `Date2`
- `Table2` with columns `Table1Id` and `Table2Id`
- `Table3` with columns `Id` and `Name`

Here is my try:

```
with tmp_tab as (
    select
        v."Name" as name
        , date_part('month', cv."OfferAcceptedDate") as MonthAcceptedName
        , date_part('month', cv."OfferSentDate") as MonthSentName
        , 1 as cntAcc
        , 1 as cntSent
        from hr_metrics."CvInfo" as cv
        join hr_metrics."CvInfoVacancy" as civ 
            on civ."CvInfosId" = cv."Id" 
        join hr_metrics."Vacancy" as v 
            on civ."VacanciesId" = v."Id" 
        where cv."OfferSentDate" is not null
        and date_part('year', cv."OfferSentDate") = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)
        group by  v."Name" , date_part('month', cv."OfferAcceptedDate"), 
        date_part('month', cv."OfferSentDate")
    )

select  distinct
    tmp_tab."name" as name,
    tmp_tab.MonthSentName as mSent,
    tmp_tab.MonthAcceptedName as mAcc,
    Sum(tmp_tab.cntSent) as sented,
    Sum(tmp_tab.cntacc) as accepted
    from tmp_tab as tmp_tab
group by tmp_tab.name, tmp_tab.MonthSentName, tmp_tab.MonthAcceptedName;
```

I need to take `Count(date2)/Count(date1)` grouped by `monthes` and `name`.
I have no idea how to do that, as there is no table with `monthes`.
DB - Postgres

sample data from comment:

```
t1
1 | 01/01/2021 | 31/03/2021 
2 | 05/01/2021 | 18/01/2021 
3 | 12/01/2021 | 31/01/2021 
4 | 13/03/2021 | 22/03/2021 


t2 
1 | 1 
2 | 1 
3 | 2 
4 | 1 

t3 
1 | SomeName1 
2 | someName2
```

Desired result:

```
Name | month | value 
SomeName1 | 1 | 1\2 
SomeName1 | 3 | 2 
SomeName2 | 1 | 1
```

Update: if `count(date2) == 0`, than `count(date2) = -1`

Comment: _"grouped by month"_ which month?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Id column in t3 is same as id column in t1?

Comment: The tables in your query are named different, which is confusing. From which of the dates should the month be calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288057/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Here code for my question thats work. And yeah, i've asked it on ru too.

```
    select name, month, sum((SRC=1)::int) as AcceptedCount, sum((SRC=2)::int) as SentCount,
       case when sum((SRC=1)::int) = 0 then -1
            else sum((SRC=2)::int)::float / sum((SRC=1)::int) end as Result
  from (
    select v.name, SRC,
           extract('month' from case SRC when 1 then OfferAcceptedDate else OfferSentDate end) as month
      from (select (date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)::char(4) || '-01-01')::timestamptz as from_date) x
      cross join (select 1 as SRC union all select 2) s
      join CvInfo as cv on (SRC=1 and cv.OfferAcceptedDate >= from_date and cv.OfferAcceptedDate < from_date + interval '1 year')
                        or (SRC=2 and cv.OfferSentDate >= from_date and cv.OfferSentDate < from_date + interval '1 year')
       join CvInfoVacancy as civ on civ.CvInfosId = cv.Id
       join Vacancy as v on civ.VacanciesId = v.Id
      where case SRC when 1 then OfferAcceptedDate else OfferSentDate end is not null
  ) x
  group by name, month
```